Looking for a historical book set in London whose main character is a young boy
I've forgotten most of this book's plot, but I read this book around 6 or so years ago. Its main character is a young boy, either in his early teens or nearly a teenager. His mother died and left him with a silver locket. At the start, he's trying to steal the locket back but gets caught. The setting is London, around the 1600s or 1700s, because he is sent to a colony (I think America). Is there any book that matches this description?

The 'reason that you've forgotten' is presumably transportation (a common punishment).

@KateBunting No, it's because he stole the locket. I removed that part so others won't misunderstand the grammar.

He's trying to steal the locket back from whom or where?

@Ayshe I think someone took the locket and then he tried to steal it back, but I don't remember from who or where.
